# Is 35.+(10) still called infix notation?

Tags: scala, math, syntax, functional-programming

I nearly talked about

```
35.+(10)
```

as an example of postfix notation because I understood

```
35 + 10
```

to be infix notation (at least everyone talks about that as an example of infix notation). But that's wrong isn't it?

```
35 10 +
```

would be postfix.

**So how do I distinguish between the first two examples by name? Are they both "infix" but the second just a neater way?**

Comment: `5 + 7` is infix.  It is also point-free style, which is the customary way to write symbolic methods in Scala.  `5.+(7)` is standard method call style.

Comment: I think 35 + 10 is just syntactic sugar for 35.+(10). Both should be infix.
Looked for a source and just found wikipedia. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_(programming_language)#Syntactic_flexibility

Comment: @Rex Kerr `5 + 7` is not point-free! Only functions can be point-free! A function definition is point free if it is completely eta-reduced (i.e. not identifying it's arguments): For example `product = foldr (*) 1` (Haskell) is a point-free definition where the list argument is not identified. Writing point-free style in Scala is often not possible, because most functions are defined as member functions, making it impossible to eta-reduce the first argument.

Comment: Perhaps better referred to as “dotless” or “dot-free” method invocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it is still "infix".

Postfix means that all operands to an operator come in the stream before the operator itself. (an example is the factorial "!" operator in mathematics)

Prefix means the operator comes before the operands (an example is the "negate"/"-" operator to make a number negative).

Infix simply means that the operator is somewhere between the operands.

Answer (score 1):

To decide how to name the application syntax, break the fragment up into tokens.

> 35.+(10)

is

> [35] [.] [+] [(] [10] [)]

dropping the redundant parens, and let's name '.' as 'apply' we get:

> [35] [apply] [+] [10]

So it most certainly is infix, as the binary operator is between the first and second argument.

It's just a bit noisy for what is also written as `35 + 10`